# How do I clear state such as permission decisions from the Visual Studio/MAUI WebView?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, webview, maui, maui-windows

I'm working on MAUI app with a WebView and have gotten into a state where the Camera permission has been denied. I'd like to clear or change this, but the WebView doesn't offer a UI for doing so like a browser does. I'm only trying to debug for Windows locally at this point. How can I clear this state for local development? Like, just reset the WebView to act as if I've never run the app before. Thanks.

Extra info: this is a Blazor MAUI hybrid app. I'm inspecting the embedded WebView using Edge DevTools (the default for this type of project).

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more elegant solution, but I finally resolved this by changing the `Package name` in the `.appxmanifest` file, running the app, and then changing it back.